# How to make stylesheet linked in parent HTML accessible to child HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have parent HTML where I have linked a custom stylesheet to it. The parent HTML has one more child HTML in it which gets launched on click of a button.

This child HTML will be created dynamically on click of a button using a jQuery plugin, the child HTML will be modal where a YouTube video will be embedded.

As I do not have access to child HTML elements or style sheets associated with it as it is a dynamically built, how can I override the child HTML styles using my custom built style sheet.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="showYTVideo.js"></script>
    <link href="showYtVideo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>YouTube Modal</h1>
    <button type="button" class="show-modal">Thumbnail</button>  
    <!-- child HTML will be populated here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question **How to make stylesheet linked in parent HTML accessible to child HTML** it comes "as is" by default. If you load html into html, it will take the stylings of the parent.

For your second question **how can I override the child HTML styles using my custom built style sheet.** Just use accurated selectors as the following example:

```css
/* OWN styles */

div.one > div.two > p.three > span.four {color: red; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.2em;}


/* external styles */

p > .four{color:blue; font-weight:normal; font-size: 2rem;}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <p class="three">
      <span class="four">
        lalalalala
      </span>
     </p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

As you can see, the "external" are loaded after internal (own) styles, but, as our CSS selector are more accurated than externals, ours takes effect, ignoring others. (Read about [CSS priorities](http://monc.se/kitchen/38/cascading-order-and-inheritance-in-css))

Hope it helps!